# Evenly underline a formatted text so that descenders (like "y") overlap the line

Tags: tikz-pgf, underline

I am trying to underline a formatted text.

What am I trying to do is the following:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\udensdot}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[densely dotted] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\udensdot{    
        \textcolor{blue}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{~#1~}}
    }
}
\begin{document}
I go to \ans{the} cinema in \ans{the} evening \ans{eventually}.
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following result, where the last line is below the others:

[image: result line]

I would like all lines to be at the same level and so that descenders (like "y" here) overlap the underline, but I can not figure out how to achieve that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the depth of descenders depends on the font.  `\dp\strutbox` is the standard, and usually includes a gap (`\baselineskip=\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you wish black dots to cover the blue color of the textual phrase like in this picture?:

[image]

If not, but you wish dots to be on the baseline of the line of text and the blue color of the textual phrase to cover the black color of the dots, you can create a node with a `\phantom`, draw the line and then create a node with text instead of a `\phantom`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\udensdot}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {\phantom{\mbox{#1}}};
        \draw[densely dotted] (todotted.base west) -- (todotted.base east);
        \node at (todotted) [inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] {\mbox{#1}};
    }%
}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\udensdot{%
        \textcolor{blue}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{~#1~}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
I go to \ans{the} cinema in \ans{the} evening \ans{eventually}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice that the dots from the answer above where above the blue text. 
Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating your own underline in TikZ, you could use a package like `lua-ul`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\zapf}{Zapf Chancery}

\makeatletter
\newunderlinetype\beginUnderDot{\cleaders\hb@xt@ .44em{\hss\raisebox{-0.5ex}{.}\hss}}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand\underDot{+m}{{\beginUnderDot#1}}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{%
  {\zapf\underDot{~\textcolor{blue}{#1}~}}%
}
\begin{document}
I go to \ans{the} cinema in \ans{the} evening \ans{eventually}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `ulem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\dotuline{~\textcolor{blue}{#1}~}}%
}
\begin{document}
I go to \ans{the} cinema in \ans{the} evening \ans{eventually}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for the response. 
Note that in the code you have provided the ``\fontfamily{pzc}`` doesn't do the job. Moreover, overall look of the result given by ``lua-ul`` is uglier then the custom TikZ solutions by Ulrich Diez and matexmatics.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov The lua-ul approach gives you full control about the dot size and positioning. Just change the layout to whatever you like.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use `base west` and `base east` in the command `\udensdot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\udensdot}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[densely dotted] (todotted.base west) -- (todotted.base east);
    }%
}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\udensdot{%
        \textcolor{blue}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{~#1~}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
I go to \ans{the} cinema in \ans{the} evening \ans{eventually}.
\end{document}
```